# How to build an infinite tree hierarchy?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview, hierarchical-data

I've been working on this since yesterday and I'm completely stumped. I'm working in VB.NET but I can understand C# if you'd prefer to answer it that way.

Basically I have items from a SQL database with IDs and parent IDs and I need to put them in a tree like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>Some item
        <ul>
            <li>Another item
                <ul>
                    <li>This could go forever
                        <ul>
                            <li>Still going</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Currently I have a nested repeater which works but it only gets me to the second level. It looks something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="parent" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <ul>
            <li><span><%#Container.DataItem("Name")%></span>
                <asp:Repeater ID="child" DataSource='<%#CType(Container.DataItem, DataRowView).Row.GetChildRows("relation")%>' runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span><%#Container.DataItem("Name")%></span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The relation is like this:

```
ds.Relations.Add("relation",
                 ds.Tables("Items").Columns("ID"),
                 ds.Tables("Items").Columns("ParentID"),
                 False)
```

I understand why it won't work because it doesn't have a template to continue the tree. So I'm trying to figure out a way around that.

I've considered writing a function to just build the string in the code behind and stick it in the html with an asp tag. I wasn't sure how to go about this while pulling the data out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution though it's extremely inefficient. In case anyone stumbles across my question this will at least get you by. For large amounts of data it could take up to a full minute to load.

If anyone could comment on how to make this more efficient that would be nice.

Code behind:

```
Private Dim dt As New DataTable

Public Function BuildTree(ByVal ID As String) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    dt = YourDatabase.GetChildren(ID) '<-- You'll have to write this function

    sb.AppendLine("")

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        sb.AppendLine("<ul>")
        If dt.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                sb.AppendLine("<li>" & row("ItemName"))
                ' Recursive call
                sb.AppendLine(BuildTree(row("ID").ToString))
                sb.AppendLine("</li>")
            Next
        Else
            sb.AppendLine("<li>" & dt.Rows(0)("ItemName").ToString & "</li>")
        End If
        sb.AppendLine("</ul>")
    End If

    Return sb.ToString
End Function
```

Then in your aspx page do something like this:

```
<%#BuildTree(Container.DataItem("ID").ToString)%>
```

**EDIT:** Declaring the DataTable outside of the function helps the efficiency a bit.